# OnLocationChanged is not called

Tags: android, android-mapview

`OnLocationChanged()` is not called though requestLocationUpdates is added and so, map is not showing its current location.
Map is always showing its default mock location. Please suggest to overcome the issue. I have added all the necessary permissions in manifest file.
Note: I don't want last location using getLastKnownLocation, instead I want current location. I waited for the device get the fix, sometimes the GPS needs more time than usual, but still no improvement. I traveled almost 10 kilometers with the device on too. :-).
Here is the code which I used.

```
public class TestingmapActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

private MapController myMapController;
private MapView mapView;
private LocationManager myLocationManager;
private double m_dLati = 12.913469, m_dLongi = 77.609761;
String provider;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    myMapController = mapView.getController();
    provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    myMapController.setZoom(14); // Zoon 1 is world view
    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0,this);
    setMockLocation(m_dLati, m_dLongi, 500);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    startListening();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    stopListening();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    stopListening();
    super.onStop();
}

private void startListening() {
    if (myLocationManager != null) {
        myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
}

private void stopListening() {
    if (myLocationManager != null)
        myLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

private void setMockLocation(double latitude, double longitude,
        float accuracy) {
    Log.v("", "provider name= " + provider);
    myLocationManager.addTestProvider(provider, "requiresNetwork" == "",
            "requiresSatellite" == "", "requiresCell" == "",
            "hasMonetaryCost" == "", "supportsAltitude" == "",
            "supportsSpeed" == "", "supportsBearing" == "",
            android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
            android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    Location newLocation = new Location(provider);
    newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
    newLocation.setAccuracy(accuracy);
    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "Mock: New Latitude = " + newLocation.getLatitude()
                    + " New Longitude = " + newLocation.getLongitude(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    myLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(provider, true);
    myLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus(provider,
            LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
    myLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(provider, newLocation);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.v("LocationListener", "onLocationChanged " + location.getLatitude()
            + " , " + location.getLongitude());
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
    myMapController.animateTo(point);       
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION" />
```

Thanks,
Biplab

Comment: What about to accept answer of your last question?

Comment: sorry, I didnt know that. I have marked the accept answer tick button for the last question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Are you checking it on device?? And are you testing it outside??

Comment: Why don't you want to use getLastKnownLocation()?

Comment: I think, last location will be useful for the last fix. I want something like on the move location update for navigation system. Will last location help ? I am not sure.

Comment: @sandip: Yes I am checking this on device. And testing it outside.

Comment: getLastKnownLocation() is the only method which will give you update on your changed location. Its works on specified criteria. Distance and time for update location.

Comment: using getCurrentKnownLocation I am getting last location but it is not giving my current location..

Answer (score 0):

You  need to override provider in your `setMockLocation` method. 
Please check once again that method.

Comment: setMockLocation is not an overriden function. I have written that to set some location in the map as per the latitude and longitude passed as arguements.

Comment: @SandipJadhav You mean `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi`?

Comment: I am implementing onLocationChangeListener

Answer (score -1):

Try to use it outside from room..because GPS doesn't work in indoor..depending upon the place..it works perfectely in outdoor..

Comment: I have covered almost 10 km area to test the application. It didnt work.

Comment: I doubt so as of April 2012 but it's definitely not a problem now Hulk